# Scringo Android Flaws : No support for Amazon store apps

Tags: android, facebook, google-play, amazon-appstore, scringo

I have done my research and now face a very strange problem and no support from the Team @ scringo , the Android sdk or the jar for Scringo has sufficient evidence that when i click invite friends to my app via Facebook , it only supports a Google Play Store link and not amazon store links

Any way to override this , the Class under question is : ScringoFacebookAgentInternal.java found in the jar file , where the Facebook invite or share methods just support pla store links and no provision for Amazon app store , am I the only one to suffer this ??

### Note : How to override this method , no supported APi docs on the same

The code in question is from within the jar Class files :

> public void invite(Context context, long id) /* 431:    */   { /*
>   432:357 */     Bundle params = new Bundle(); /* 433:358 */
>
>   params.putString("to", id); /* 434:359 */     params.putString("name",
>   ScringoPreferences.instance.applicationData.facebookInviteTitle); /*
>   435:360 */     params.putString("link",
>   "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" +
>   context.getPackageName());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a fix for you. It isn't a pretty one but it will work.

In **Scringo Project** locate the xml file called scringo_feedback_root. You can find it by going to **res/layout/scringo_feedback_root**.

This file contains the xml appearance for the Feedback option on the Scringo SideBar.

Next, change the following code

```
com.scringo.features.ScringoListItem
android:id="@+id/scringoFeedbackRootFacebook"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

to

```
com.scringo.features.ScringoListItem
android:id="@+id/scringoFeedbackRootFacebook"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:visibility = "gone"/>
```

Change the visibility to gone for any option that you have an issue with that is non-compatible with Amazon App Store policy.

Next locate the **scringo_strings.xml** file by navigating to res/values/scringo_strings.xml and change the following strings

**scringo_text_post_feedback_popup_message_5stars**

**scringo_text_rate_us_description**

**scringo_text_claim_it**

change them to Amazon Appstore instead of Google Play. =)

Next, in your activity after scringoObject.init() call

```
Scringo.builtForStore(ScringoBuiltForStore.AMAZON);
```

next you need to remove the claim for a free app when taking quizzes, since this also directs to the Google Play Store instead of the Amazon App Store. =)

navigate to **res/layout/scringo_quiz_end_dialog.xml**

find the linearlayout with id of **android:id="@+id/scringoQuizEndFreeGameButton"**
add **android:alpha="0.0"** to that layout item. android:visibility = "gone" and android:clickable = "false" has no effect. Make the view invisible by changing the alpha to 0.

next you need to take care of the invite section, since it also links directly to the google play store.

navigate to xml called scringo_find_friends_root.xml by going to res/layout/scringo_find_friends_root.xml in the Scringo project.

located the following code

```
<com.scringo.features.ScringoListItem
android:id="@+id/scringoFacebook"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

add an android:visibility = "gone" to that code, like you did with the scringo_feedback_root.xml, if there are othere options in there that need to be removed, then remove them by changing the visibility.

You should be done now, but your users on Amazon will have a slightly different experience then your users on Google Play. Positive thing though is that all of your users from Amazon and Google Play will be under one app id, which should increase user activity in your app.

Hopefully the Scringo Team will fix this in an update soon. Until then, we must improvise.

**ALTERNATIVE OPTIONS - ?**

Option 1:

Create a new Application ID on www.scringo.com and change the links there to point to your amazon appstore application for the feedback tab/ share link. I don't like this option since it separates your two communities, instead of uniting them.

Option 2:

Disable the Feedback and Invite option at www.scringo.com and provide another way for users to send you feedback, or invite their friends. Also not good since Scringo has already taken care of this for you.

**ALL DONE**